# Android - Check if app already installed in Emulator

Tags: android

I am working on an app which will use the information of another existing app.
How can I check app is installed or not in the **Emulator**.

I tried below function:

```
boolean isInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.example.myapp", context.getPackageManager())


public static boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        return packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).enabled;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

above function returns **FALSE**.
But app is already installed in Emulator.

Comment: what do you mean by its not working? what does it do?

Comment: Is the emulator using Android 11? see https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-get-users-installed-apps-in-android-11-b4a4d2754286

Comment: yes..Emulator using Android 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing installed package data has changed for Android 11.

You need to have extra permissions to be able to query whats installed.

If you know what specific app(s) you need to query add something like:

```
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.myapp" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

to your manifest.

See https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-get-users-installed-apps-in-android-11-b4a4d2754286 for more details